# SQL Server getting value within a week time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I need some guidance in getting value from the database within a week time period. I've figured out how to use `DATEPART` where I can do `DATEPART(wk, date_value) = DATEPART(datepart, GETDATE())` but what I can't figure out is how to do a specific day of the week. Like I only want to retrieve information from this Tuesday to next Tuesday. Can anyone offer anyone offer any guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "this Tuesday"? Does that mean the nearest Tuesday in the future relative to now? The Tuesday that is in the same week as the current day? Something else?

Comment: Tuesday within the current week too next Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do something like this:

```
Set DateFirst 1;

Select DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 3
        , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) As ThisWeekTuesday
    , DateAdd(d, 7, DateAdd(d, -DatePart(dw, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 3
        , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) As TuesdayAfterThat
```

In MIcrosoft Access, you would do something like:

```
Select DateAdd("d", -DatePart("w", Now()) + 3, Now()) As ThisWeekTuesday
    , DateAdd("d", 7, DateAdd("d", -DatePart("w", Now()) + 3
        , Now())) As TuesdayAfterThat
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a Dates table - store one record per day, with fields for SQLDate, DateAsText, Year, Month, MonthAsText, DayOfWeek, DayOfWeekAsText, etc.  Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(SQLDate)
FROM
  Dates
WHERE
      SQLDate > SYSDATETIME()
  AND DayOfWeekText = 'Tuesday'
```

If you'd rather not go through that right now, you can also use DATEPART() and DATEADD().  For the next coming Tuesday, I believe this would be:

```
DECLARE @TodaysDayOfWeek = DATEPART(DW, SYSDATETIME())
SELECT
  CASE WHEN @TodaysDayOfWeek < 3 DATEADD( 3 - @TodaysDayOfWeek, SYSDATETIME())
       ELSE                      DATEADD(10 - @TodaysDayOfWeek, SYSDATETIME() END
```

I don't have MS SQL handy to confirm this, but it should work if DW starts at 1 for Sunday and ends with 7 for Saturday (this can vary depending on your config).  Note that, if called on a Tuesday it will give *next* Tuesday, not today; to reverse this behavior, change "< 3" to "<= 3".

Comment: Sorry, but creating Dates tables should be the last resort when no other option works. In the scenario you present, this could be solved through any number of other ways without adding a maintenance/administrative task like this.